# Team foundation server multiple user

Tags: tfs

How does the multiple user work with the same .net project Using team foundation server?What are all the things needs to be created for working on a team project?

Answer (score 0):

Seems you need to read the documents first. Refer to [VSTS and TFS-New User Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/user-guide/what-is-tfs) for details.

Simply say you need to do below things:

1. [Create a team project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/accounts/create-team-project?tabs=vsts)
2. [Add users to projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/accounts/add-team-members-vs)
3. [Connect to team projects](http://Connect%20to%20team%20projects)
4. TFVC - [Add your project to source control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/set-up-team-foundation-version-control-your-dev-machine)  Git- [Share your code
   with Visual Studio 2017 and VSTS Git](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/share-your-code-in-git-vs-2017)

.
.
.

Just following the User Guide to do others.